# Open-Source DES for perishable goods

Tags: simulation, supply-chain

Can anybody point to examples of using open-source discrete event simulation packages (`simpy`, `salabim`, `simmer`, etc.) to model inventory policies for perishable goods?

I'm looking to make a proof-of-concept simulation to evaluate push-based stocking decisions under conditions of highly uncertain demand. I could probably code this as series of big if-loops, but wanted to see if there's anything out there to review. All I've seen in Google is academic papers recommending a new algorithm!

Comment: There are multiple approaches to simulation that might involve perishable goods. Can you elaborate more on how the logic of the simulation would be different?